# Is it possible to have Html.ActionLink add URL params automatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What I'd like is for all urls to contain a certain parameter without having to pass it to the views and add it to ActionLink through the routevalues param. I have a section in my site that I want to keep track of a "return param" for all links. It works fine for forms since Html.BeginForm sets the action to the exact current url already.

So, if the page I'm at is

```
/MyController/MyAction/300?ReturnTo=100
```

and I output

```
Html.ActionLink("Next Screen", "MyOtherAction")
```

I'd like to see

```
<a href="/MyController/MyOtherAction/300?ReturnTo=100">Next Screen</a>
```

without having to do

```
Html.ActionLink("Next Screen", "MyOtherAction", new {ReturnTo = Model.ReturnTo})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own HtmlHelper extension that does this by calling Html.ActionLink, and combining the query strings.  Use the ViewContext to get at the current query string.

Comment: That sounds pretty good. Does it strike you as breaking mvc conventions to access HttpContext.Current.Request in a view helper?

Comment: You don't need to, exactly. It is available via the helper argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Html.ActionLink("Next Screen", "MyOtherAction", new {Model.ReturnTo})
```

The link will now appear the way you want it to be.

Comment: You've got to read the whole question before answering, the line you wrote is the exact line I was wondering how not to write.